# Angular loads individual views without parent template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one page that contains a ui-view. When you visit that page (/user/), it loads /user/login template into the view by default. You can hit signup, which will load the signup (/user/signup) template into the view. However, if you directly go to /user/signup, it shows the barebones form. Is it possible to show the /user page with the signup template (loaded in the view) when a user goes to /user/signup?

Relevant code:

/user.ejs:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ui-view="container" class="auth-container">
    <span>Sign in</span>
    <form ng-submit="login()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" autofocus>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
    </form>
    <a ui-sref="signup">Sign Up</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/public/javascripts/authController.js

```
var app = angular.module("myapp.auth", ["ui.router"]);

app.config([
  "$stateProvider",
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("user", {
      parent: "root",
      url: “/user”,
      templateUrl: "/welcome",
      controller: "AuthController",
    })
    .state("login", {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/user/login",
      views: {
        "container@": {
          templateUrl: "welcome/login",
          controller: "AuthController"
        }
      }
    })
  }
]);
```

welcome/login.ejs:

```
<span>Sign in</span>
<form ng-submit="login()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
</form>
<a ui-sref="signup">Sign Up</a>
```

And lastly, the node.js routing:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/user", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("user", {
    title: "Express"
  });
});

router.get("/user/login", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("auth/login", {
    title: "Express"
  });
});
```

So if I go to `localhost/user`, it directly loads the `login` view in the ui-view. However, if I go to `localhost/user/login`, it loads and shows only the contents of the `login.ejs`, without any part of the user.ejs template.

What I really want is the following:

1. User goes to `localhost/user`. Angular sees that no specific module was requested, so it shows `user.ejs` and automatically loads the `login.ejs` view into the `ui-view`.
2. User goes to `localhost/user/login`. Angular sees that `login` was requested, so it shows `user.ejs` and loads `login.ejs` into ui-view.
3. User goes to `localhost/user/register`. Angular sees that `signup` was requested, so it shows `user.ejs` and loads `signup.ejs` (not shown here) into ui-view.

Any pointers?

Comment: Is that whacky quote character (`“myapp.auth"`) in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, looks like directly copying did not work. I have fixed that part.

Comment: I think you should focus on 1 type of router, express router / angular router. the angular router is meant for SPA so the page won't really change (you can notice in the url the hash # before the route) in the express it load the page you specified which is the login but only with the template and without all whats around it.

Comment: I have been trying to do a combination of both. There are some places where express is significantly more useful (in this app, specifically) than angular and vice versa.

Comment: Authentication and signing up is handled on the same parent page. Other parts of the site actually require navigating between pages.